# Making a discord bot to send an image through an embed with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I tried making a discord bot with discord.py that sends a picture when it sees the command ".pic". When I run the program and try the .pic command, the picture doesn't send and an embed doesn't send. I have a small program that does cooldowns. I do see the cooldown function working even though the embeds and pictures are not there. I also receive no error code in the console
Here is my code:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")


@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown):  
        return await ctx.send('The command **{}** is still on cooldown for {:.2f}'.format(ctx.command.name, error.retry_after))

pictures =["https://i.imgur.com/LAmHP4K.jpg","https://i.imgur.com/sXS290O.jpg","https://i.imgur.com/Ar7Ihs5.jpg"]

@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.user)  
async def pic(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(color = discord.colour.red())
  random_link = random.choice(pictures)
  embed.set_image(url = random_link)
  await ctx.send(embed = embed)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: `ctx.send` is a coroutine, it should be awaited

Comment: I changed my code to ctx.send(embed = embed) but it's still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discord.color` is the module, `discord.Color()` is the class. Remember that case sensitivity is very important in python. You need `discord.Color.red()` because you need the red method of the `discord.Color` class.

Comment: Thank you! it fixed it. I've been trying to get this to work for hours and it was just a silly mistake (as usual) lol.

Comment: Np, just remember to accept the solution if it helped.